# Using rtools grep/pipe combination through a system call

Tags: r, windows

I have a file called `goodfile`. Lets say the contents are

```
badline
goodline
badline
goodline
badline
badline
```

On a windows machine I want to filter this file to get only the "goodline"s before reading it to save on memory costs. Thankfully, the rtools installation comes with `grep` that should allow me to do that. I should be able to do

```r
if(!pkgbuild::has_rtools()){
    stop('install rtools')
}
rtoolsPath = pkgbuild::rtools_path()
grep = file.path(rtoolsPath,'grep.exe')


command = paste(grep, "goodline goodfile")
system(command)
```

and get

```
goodline
goodline
```

However when I try to pipe the output to a file by doing

```r
command = paste(grep, "goodline goodfile > betterfile")
system(command)
```

I get

```
goodfile:goodline
goodfile:goodline
/usr/bin/grep: >: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/grep: betterfile: No such file or directory
```

This error message and the "betterfile" is not generated.

If I take the same command and run it on my command line, it just works, if  I do the same `system` call with regular `grep` on R in linux machine it just works, so I can't see what the problem is.

I was able to find an alternative way to get the file by doing

```r
system2(grep, 
        args = c('goodline','goodfile'),stderr = 'betterfile',stdout = 'betterfile')
```

but still curious why the pipe doesn't work

Comment: The short answer is that `system` is complicated: you are better off using `shell` or `system2`. From the helpfile: "… it cannot be assumed that redirection or piping will work in system (redirection sometimes does, but we have seen cases where it stopped working after a Windows security patch), and system2 (or shell) must be used on Windows."